# ASWebAuthenticationSession on macOS 12.4 do not work properly

Tags: flutter, macos-monterey, aswebauthenticationsession

I'm using ASWebAuthenticationSession authorization for my application.
It works fine before macOS12.4, but occur unresponse's issue.
After "session.start success", Click Cancel or Continue and there is no response.

[image: The window that can't be closed]

```
        var session = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init(url: url, callbackURLScheme: "http", completionHandler: completionHandler)

        guard let provider = NSApplication.shared.keyWindow!.contentViewController as? FlutterViewController else {
            result(FlutterError(code: "FAILED", message: "Failed to aquire root FlutterViewController" , details: nil))
            return
        }

        session.presentationContextProvider = provider

        if(!session.start()) {
            NSLog("session.start  fail");
        } else {
            NSLog("session.start success");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I just noticed I did not read correctly and missed the fact that this question was for macOS, not iOS. I still hope one of those answers might lead to a solution.

I have noticed 2 things that seem incorrect to me.

---

The first one is that you need a strong reference for your session. This limitation is only valid for iOS version < 13.0.

This means, the session variable must "outlive" the invoked method it was started in, e.g. setting a session attribute for the whole class.
I cannot see something similar in the code snippet you provided, it looks like a scoped variable to me.

From Apples [documentation for this feature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession/2990953-start):

> For iOS apps with a deployment target earlier than iOS 13, your app
> must keep a strong reference to the session to prevent the system from
> deallocating the session while waiting for authentication to complete.

---

The second thing is your callback URL scheme seems to be set to `https`.
The scheme should match your apps bundle ID.
It must be configured in your `Info.plist` file. [Here's an example how to achieve this](https://medium.com/@cafielo/custom-urlscheme-in-ios-be74a45e212b). It should actually be something like `com.company.myappname` instead of `http`. Your authentication provider would also need to redirect to `com.company.myappname://someurl` to make this work. Please note the `://` must not be part of the callback URL scheme, only the part before that.